# Django update a page on POST.get

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Django project where i use NFC keychains. When a keychain is read, the reader sends a HTTP POST request to my Django server, which is now basically displaying the key that has been read.

What causes the problem is that in order to show that the keychain has been read i need to refresh the page.

Is there any way to show the changes immediately, or force a refresh on the browser from the server when a POST request is executed? I have read that Ajax might be capable for this, but i dont know Ajax. If Ajax would be the solution, can anyone show me a working example?

Comment: What is the relationship between the browser that is displaying the page and the reader that reads the keychain?

Comment: @DanielRoseman They are connected via internet. No direct cable connection

Comment: But my point is that the POST request that notifies that the key has been read is not coming from the machine that is viewing the page?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, the POST request is sent from a remote machine to my computer which is viewing the page

Answer (score 2):

Completely up to you but you could HTTP POST whatever request data you need to a view, then collect that data - do you manipulations and then send back a JsonResponse (which Django handles fairly well).

In your Javascript/jQuery/React/Vue code you could then collect the response object and manipulate the front end if a valid keychain is returned...

Typical usage is like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def end_point(request):
   context = {}
   if request.method == 'POST':
       token = request.POST.get('token', None)
       if token is not None: 
           token = 'Ax44sX%4adLJ8dBt6J@XKas12cvozlp'
           context = { 'data': token }
           return JsonResponse(context)
       else:
           context = { 'message': 'There doesn\'t look to be any token here, keep looking...' }
           return JsonResponse(context)               
   return render(request, 'index.html', context, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

You need to "mop" up the JsonResponse with jQuery, something like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:8000/endpoint",
   success: function(response) {
       // Do something with response here!! Validate, manipulate, etc etc
       console.log(response.data);
   }
});
```

The context object you pass back will be accessible within the response object.

Be careful tho - you'll need to pass through a valid `{% csfr_token %}` (this can be done when you setup you POST request). *I can explain if needed how to do this.*

Where I have rendered a JsonResponse you could also render a normal HttpResponse (with the page refreshing), passing your token value into the same context:

```
def end_point(request):
       context = {}
       if request.method == 'POST':
           token = request.POST.get('token', None)
           if token is not None: 
               token = 'Ax44sX%4adLJ8dBt6J@XKas12cvozlp'
               context['data'] = token
               return render(request, 'index.html', context, content_type='application/xhtml+xml') 
           else:
               context = { 'message': 'There doesn\'t look to be any token here, keep looking...' }
               return JsonResponse(context)               
       return render(request, 'index.html', context, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

And then in your `index.html` template file:

```
{% if data %}
<p>Your token is: {{ data }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sounds nice, i will try it tomorrow thanks. Can i somehow pass the response from the ajax function to the html template itself?

Comment: You could do - you can POST the data - then render another response with a modified context object with your token added, and display this in your template.

Comment: I dont really get it. So the NFC send a POST to the server, and the server sends a JsonResponse to the template and is received by Ajax if i get it right. All i would like to do is to access that information outside of the Ajax function, so basically somewhere in the <body> tag, and be able to update some values without the need of a page refresh

Comment: If you want to do it without a page refresh you'll either want AJAX or a websocket. Websockets are an extremely advanced topic. Once you have the object or array or variable tou want in the AJAX response, you can begin to use Vanilla javascript or jQuery to update the DOM (i.e., the document, so you can update something somewhere between the <body> tags.

Comment: And how can i do that with jQuery?

Comment: Wow, there’s so many methods. Do you know which element you want to target?